# Filtering Listboxes in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, listbox, filtering, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to filter the contents of a Listbox in a Windows Forms application?

The DataSource of my ListBox is a BindingSource containing a bunch of DTOs in an:

```
IList<DisplayDTO>
```

I want to filter on the DTO property that is specified in the ListBox's DisplayMember.

The text to be filtered on is provided in a separate Text Box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource.Filter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'",
                                         listBox.DisplayMember,
                                         textBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
}
```

EDIT: this works only if the underlying data source (`bindingSource.DataSource`) implements `IBindingListView`. In the FCL, only the `DataView` class implements this interface.

You can create your own implementation by inheriting from `BindingList<T>`. Here's [an article](http://www.nablasoft.com/alkampfer/index.php/2008/11/22/extend-bindinglist-with-filter-functionality/) that explains how to add the filter functionality. You can also find various implementations of `SortableBindingList` on Google.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, with a few variations, and still haven't been able to get it to work. I read that it could be something to do with the container that is used within the BindingSource.

Changing it to a BindingList didn't help any.

Comment: Unfortunately the `BindingList<T>` implementation provided with the .NET framework doesn't support sorting and filtering... Here's a post that explains how to add the filter functionality : http://www.nablasoft.com/alkampfer/index.php/2008/11/22/extend-bindinglist-with-filter-functionality/.