# Remove items from ListBox when DataSource is set

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

See I have a HashSet with several values, this values can contain for example numbers like **4141234567**, **4241234567**, **4261234567** and so on. I put a radioButton1 in my UserControl and I want when I click this just the numbers with 414 and 424 remains on my ListBox, for that I wrote this code:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bdHashSet = new HashSet<string>(bd);

        if (openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() != "")
        {
            foreach (var item in bdHashSet)
            {
                if (item.Substring(1, 3) != "414" || item.Substring(1, 3) != "424")
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

> Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

What is the proper way to remove the non wanted items from the list without remove them from the HashSet? I'll add later a optionButton for numbers that begin with 0416 and 0426 and also a optionButton to fill the listBox with original values, any advice?

Comment: Instead of removing items in the `ListBox`, you can remove items in an Object assigned to its `DataSource` and call `Bind()` method of the object.

Comment: @lexeRoy I'm not a C# expert so I'll need your help on this, could you please write a small piece of code so I can understand how it should be of course is not much to ask

Comment: See my answer below. There'll be no remove items because we are creating new `HashSet` copying a private object named `bd` and selecting what filter we want to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bdHashSet = new HashSet<string>(bd);

    listBox1.Datasource = null;
    listBox1.Datasource =  bdHashSet.Where(s => (s.StartsWith("414") || s.StartsWith("424"))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: it will remove also from bdHashSet and I don't want that because I have another button to show all the values again including also the numbers with 426 and others

Comment: also I tried your solution and get this error `Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.`

Comment: aparently it works, no error appears but it doesn't remove nothing, don't know if Substring is correct or something else but all values remain

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bdHashSet = new HashSet<string>(bd);
    listBox1.Datasource = bdHashSet.Select(s => (s.Substring(1, 3) == "414" || s.Substring(1, 3) == "424"));

    //After setting the data source, you need to bind the data
    listBox1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error message `Can not resolve symbol DataBind()` and also your solution will remove items from HashSet to and I need all because I'll allow to show them later with other optionButton

Comment: Now, if you don't want to alter its DataSource by bind it again, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419930/filtering-listboxes-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can select the elements with linq and then reassign the listBox with the result. In that way you dont need to remove elements from the list and you can keep the elements of the HashSet.

Comment: but select elements with LINQ doesn't mean remove elements from HashSet? Is not the same?

Comment: No, is not the same. Because you are only selecting the items and assigning to the list. You are not removing the items from the HashSet, so the objects still lives and still keeping the relation with the HashSet.

Comment: so basically is what damith and lexeroy are trying to do or not?

Comment: Yes, the code that they post is close to the idea that i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BindingSource` object. Bind it with DataSource and then use the `RemoveAt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem).Row;
((DataTable)listBox1.DataSource).Rows.Remove(dr);
```